# Laravel version 5.4 Class '\App\User::class' not found

Tags: php, laravel, classnotfoundexception

Specific error :

`Class '\App\User::class' not found (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\contrex\resources\views\login.blade.php`)

I know this problem has been posted many times but i really can't find the solution.

I tried to create a directory "Models" so i can have all my models there. Before doing that it was working just fine so i tried to change the settings back to where it was - but now it doesn't work.

> My User.php

```
<?php

namespace App;
namespace Illuminate\Foundation\Auth;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Auth\Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Auth\Passwords\CanResetPassword;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\Access\Authorizable;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable as AuthenticatableContract;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Access\Authorizable as AuthorizableContract;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\CanResetPassword as CanResetPasswordContract;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;

class User extends Model implements
    AuthenticatableContract,
    AuthorizableContract,
    CanResetPasswordContract
{
    use Authenticatable, Authorizable, CanResetPassword;

    use Notifiable;

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'email', 'facebook_id',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'remember_token',
    ];


}
```

> My UserController.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\User;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class UserController extends Controller
{
    public function index(){
        echo 'index';
    }
    public function create(){
        echo 'create';
    }
    public function store(Request $request){
        echo 'store';
    }
    public function show(){
    }
    public function edit($id){
        echo 'edit';
    }
    public function update(Request $request, $id){
        echo 'update';
    }
    public function destroy($id){
        echo 'destroy';
    }

}
```

> My SocialAuthController.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\User;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Laravel\Socialite\Facades\Socialite;

class SocialAuthController extends Controller
{
    public function redirect()
    {
        return Socialite::driver('facebook')->with(['auth_type' => 'rerequest'])->redirect();
    }

    public function callback()
    {
        try {
            $user = Socialite::driver('facebook')->user();
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            return redirect('auth/facebook');
        }

        if($user->email == null)
            return Socialite::driver('facebook')->with(['auth_type' => 'rerequest'])->redirect();

        $authUser = $this->findOrCreateUser($user);

        Auth::login($authUser, true);

        return redirect()->route('login');
    }

    private function findOrCreateUser($facebookUser)
    {

        $authUser = User::where('facebook_id', $facebookUser->id)->first();

        if ($authUser){
            return $authUser;
        }

        return User::create([
            'name' => $facebookUser->name,
            'email' => $facebookUser->email,
            'facebook_id' => $facebookUser->id,
        ]);
    }

}
```

> Settings on auth.php

```
 'providers' => [
        'users' => [
            'driver' => 'eloquent',
            'model' => 'App\User::class',
        ],
```

> Settings on composer.json

```
 "autoload": {
        "classmap": [
            "database"
        ],
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "app/"
        }
    },
```

I tried different things - also running `php artisan config:clear` etc.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have two namespaces in `User.php`, so change this:

```
namespace Illuminate\Foundation\Auth;
```

to:

```
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth;
```

Comment: Thanks, also to make it work changed in `auth.php` from `'App\User::class'` to `'App\User'`